# What's the reason for applying the hash twice when hashing with salt?

Tags: hash, passwords, salt

One of the typical approaches to computing a salted hash is this:

hash(salt+hash(secret))

where `hash` is something like SHA-256 hash function - taking any size input and returning fixed size output. What's the need for the `hash(secret)`?

Why can't I just do this:

hash(salt + secret)

where `+` is simply concatenating two byte arrays?

Comment: I don't see any reason here. Do you have some examples where it is used this way?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: I've seen in multiple times in comments to a post about recent LinkedIn passwords leakage.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is for hiding the clear text password on the network.

Consider that with $H(salt || pwd)$, in a very simple system, the user would send $pwd$ and the server would compute the hash to check.
Anybody who can sniff the password from the network now cannot only log in, but also knows the password.

With $H(salt || H(pwd))$ he can only sniff the hash. He can now log in, but would still need a preimage attack to find out the actual password.

Comment: LinkedIn did not know the `secret`, they only knew `hash_without_salt(secret)`. That's what they stored in their database. So unless they waited for every person to login, the only way to add a salt, is  [to take the stored unsalted hash as input](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2840/2281#2281).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This construction has two advantages over a plain hash of param1||param2:

- It's immune to length-extensions
- You can't get collisions of the form `param1=A||B param2=C` vs. `param1=A param2=B||C`.

But neither of those is relevant to password hashing, so it doesn't offer any advantage there.

The construction looks like it's inspired by [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC):

$$ HMAC(K,m) = H((K ⊕ opad) ∥ H((K ⊕ ipad) ∥ m)) $$

---

But of course for password hashing one would not use such fast hashing constructions. Correct choices are scrypt, bcrypt, and PBKDF2. These have a designated salt parameter, so they don't need such an ad-hoc construction to mix salt and password.

---

This system has one big advantage though: You can upgrade existing hashes to it, without knowing the plaintext password. Essentially you treat $ hash(pass) $ as the new password. When upgrading an old system from a plain, unsalted hash, I'd use something like:

$ PBKDF2(LegacyHash(password), salt) $

Comment: A negation is missing in the first sentence of the last paragraph.